# Implementing my formula to automate a report

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have been trying to make my formula work in my macro, however it does not. I am trying to automate a report I created a macro where it inserts columns. I have created another macro for the formulas I manually use to generate the report. I noticed that the formula I use (index and match and more) are CSE where I have to press control, shift, and enter for it to work. Now that I got it in my macro, the result is just the entire formula string. Also, I need my formula to be implemented from the second cell of the column on until the last row. I tried to use the last row function but I believe it is not working because the function isn't. I will attach pictures of my code for reference as it might be a better explanation.

```vb
    Sub InsertColumns()

    Columns("Q:S").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("Q1").Value = "SLA (Derived)"
    Range("R1").Value = "Due Date Derived"
    Range("S1").Value = "SLA Remaining Days Derived"

    Columns("U:V").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("U1").Value = "Due Date After Reset SLA Applied"
    Range("V1").Value = "Past Due (Y/N)"

    Columns("X:X").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Range("X1").Value = "Interim Reset SLA"

    End Sub
```

```vb
    Sub Past_Due_Report()
      '
    ' Past_Due_Report Macro
     '
     '     Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+p
     '
       ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9
      Range("Q2").Select
      ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=INDEX('Initial SLA'!R1C1:R256C6,MATCH(RC[-4]&RC[-3],'Initial SLA'!R1C1:R256C1&'Initial 
        SLA'!R1C2:R256C2,0),6)"
     Range("R2").Select
     ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]+RC[-1]"
     Range("S2").Select
     ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[@[Due Date Derived]]-TODAY()"
     Range("U2").Select
     ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[@[Past Due (Y/N)]]"
     Range("V2").Select
     ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = 
        "=IF([@[Due Date After Reset SLA Applied]]<TODAY(),1,0)"
     Range("V3").Select
     End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to get a formula array using R1C1 notation: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/sumif-array-formula-in-vba-with-r1c1-notation.430785/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add a CSE formula, you may mean a formula array, you may use .FormulaArray instead of .FormulaR1C1:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaArray = "=INDEX('Initial SLA'!R1C1:R256C6,MATCH(RC[-4]&RC[-3],'Initial SLA'!R1C1:R256C1&'Initial SLA'!R1C2:R256C2,0),6)"
```

You can improve your code like this:

```
With Range("Q2")
      .FormulaArray = "=INDEX('Initial SLA'!R1C1:R256C6,MATCH(RC[-4]&RC[-3],'Initial SLA'!R1C1:R256C1&'Initial SLA'!R1C2:R256C2,0),6)"
     .Offset(0,1).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]+RC[-1]"
     .Offset(0,1).FormulaR1C1 = "=[@[Due Date Derived]]-TODAY()"
     .Offset(0,2).FormulaR1C1 = "=[@[Past Due (Y/N)]]"
     .Offset(0,1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF([@[Due Date After Reset SLA Applied]]<TODAY(),1,0)"

End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I altered my code with the with statement and it does look neater. However, I am wondering why with the with statement it is not generating my U,V, and X columns? Only the formulas are looping in for Q,R,S and it is still appearing as a text and not implementing the formula. I've been browsing to figure this out. Do you know how can I get my formulas to generate the value within the macro? Thanks in advance

Comment: remove with - end with statement, and leave as you had before, just change the FormulaR1C1 to FormulaArray at the one is needed.